# Error: WTclient - Failed to Execute OPCENUM

Tags: c++, opc

I am writing a OPC client to get and send tags to a OPC server and I've got this error:
     WTclient - Failed to Execute OPCENUM
My code is very simple and I am following an example application that I found on the internet which works perfectly.
My program compiles perfectly and runs, but when reaches the     Numbr = NumberOfOPCServers(TRUE, MachineName); line that error pops up.

My .ccp is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opcda.h"
#include "opc_ae.h"
#include "wtclientapi.h"
#include "OPC2.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int Numbr;
    MachineName = "";
    Numbr = NumberOfOPCServers(TRUE, MachineName);
    return 0;
}
```

Debugging in depth another internet example, I have found that error come from this function:

```
int CWTclientApp::GetServerListFromOPCENUM(CString pathname)
{
    IOPCServerList *gpOPC;
    HRESULT hr, hr2;
    IEnumGUID *pEnumGUID;
    CLSID catid, clsid;
    unsigned long c;
    LPOLESTR pszProgID, pszUserType;
    int i;
    OPCSVRDESCR *pSvr;

    for (i=0; i<MyServerList.GetSize(); i++)
        {
        pSvr = (OPCSVRDESCR *)MyServerList.GetAt(i);
        delete (pSvr);
        }
    MyServerList.RemoveAll();

    // create the enumerator object
    gpOPC = CreateServerEnumerator(pathname);
    if (gpOPC == NULL)
        {
        DoErrorMsg ( 0, "Failed to Execute OPCENUM");
        // revert to search of Registry if OPCENUM fails to execute
        return (GetServerListFromRegistry());
        }
............................................
```

which is called from the function NumberOfOPCServers():

```
_declspec(dllexport) int  WINAPI NumberOfOPCServers (bool UseOPCENUM, LPCSTR MachineName)
{
    CWTclientApp    *pApp;
    CString path;

    path = MachineName;
    path.MakeUpper();
    if (path == "LOCAL")
        path = "";
    else
        path = MachineName;
    pApp = (CWTclientApp *)AfxGetApp();
    if (UseOPCENUM)
        return (pApp->GetServerListFromOPCENUM(path));
    else 
        return (pApp->GetServerListFromRegistry());
}
```

Any ideas why I have this error? Looks like OPCenum.exe is not enumerating my OPC server running on my machine (local server), but why? (with the downloaded application does and with mine doesn't)

Thanks!!!!

EDIT ------------------------------------------------------------------------
CreateServerEnumerator():

```
IOPCServerList *CWTclientApp::CreateServerEnumerator (CString   PathName)
{
    HRESULT r2;
    MULTI_QI mqi;
    COSERVERINFO    sin, *sinptr;
    DWORD clsctx;

    // set up server info
    //
    if (PathName.GetLength() > 0)
        {
        sinptr = &sin;
        sin.dwReserved1 = 0;
        sin.dwReserved2 = 0;
        sin.pwszName = WSTRFromCString (PathName, FALSE);
        sin.pAuthInfo = 0;
        clsctx = CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER;
        } 
    else
        {
        sinptr = 0;     // pointer should be NULL if local
        clsctx = CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER;
        }

    // set up mqi
    //
    mqi.pIID = &IID_IOPCServerList;
    mqi.hr = 0;
    mqi.pItf = 0;    

    r2 = CoCreateInstanceEx(CLSID_OPCServerList, NULL, 
        clsctx, sinptr, 1, &mqi);    
    if (PathName.GetLength() > 0)
        WSTRFree (sin.pwszName, FALSE);    
    if (FAILED(r2) || FAILED(mqi.hr))
        return (NULL);    
    return (IOPCServerList*)mqi.pItf;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a source code to CreateServerEnumerator?

Comment: @ZbynekZ , yes, question edited.

Comment: r2 value --> r2 = 0x800401f0 : CoInitialize has not been called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call CoInitialize (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543(v=vs.85).aspx) or CoInitializeEx (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279(v=vs.85).aspx) in each thread that uses COM (OPC Classic), before invoking any other COM functions.

CoInitialize is obsolete, you should therefore rather use CoInitializeEx.

Microsoft says in their documentation to this function: "CoInitializeEx must be called at least once, and is usually called only once, for each thread that uses the COM library".

Comment: thank you for the answer. It works!. I have just called WTclientCoInit(); at the beginning of the code and WTclientCoUninit(); at the end.